# Angular NgChange and change directives dont work in case of changing value of select

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events

I'm using Angular and nice-select js plugin. This plugin creates wrapper for select, that is styled. And changes select.value. (real select is hidden) The problem is, that NgModel directive doesn't work. (It doesn't calls on value change(it needs direct interaction)) Change directive too. In case of change im using this function to save changes:

```
select_change(name){             
   this.selectedInputs[name] =(<HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementsByName(name)[0]).value;     
}
```

It calls only in case of modyfiyng real select, but not wrapper. Angular thaught that select isn't changed.

Html after plugin:

```
<select name="some_name" style="display: none;">
                         <option *ngFor="let opt of formValues.auto_type" [value]="opt.value">{{ opt.label }}</option>
                     </select>

                    <div class="nice-select open" tabindex="0">
                        <span class="current">2012</span>
                        <ul class="list">
                            <li data-value="2017" class="option">2017</li>
                            <li data-value="2018" class="option">2017</li>
                            <li data-value="etc" class="option">Etc</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

[plugin here](http://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/)

Comment: show html with the wrapper and plugin reference

Comment: [plugin here](http://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/)